# Improve Syntax on Multiple If Statements?

Tags: jquery, loops, syntax, if-statement

Is there a way to make this prettier;

```
if ($("#Input").text === "A") { sOutput = "a"; lColor = "red"; }
if ($("#Input").text === "B") { sOutput = "b"; lColor = "orange"; }
if ($("#Input").text === "C") { sOutput = "c"; lColor = "yellow"; }
if ($("#Input").text === "D") { sOutput = "d"; lColor = "green"; }
if ($("#Input").text === "E") { sOutput = "e"; lColor = "blue"; }
if ($("#Input").text === "F") { sOutput = "f"; lColor = "violet"; }
...
```

The real code is much more extensive, with && and || between different variables. But each line follows the same syntax save the 'letter(s)' I'm looking for, and the variables I set. It just feels wasteful to me that I have so many ifs.

*The code is dummy code to illustrate my point.

*EDIT*

Dummy code isn't illustrating my point, so here's a sample of the real;

```
    if ($(".Fig_Main").hasClass("Active")) {
        sect_1 =  (($(".Fig_A").hasClass("Active")) && ($(".Fig_1").hasClass("Active"))) ? "Slide_A1"
              : (($(".Fig_A").hasClass("Active")) && ($(".Fig_B").hasClass("Active"))) ? "Slide_AB"
              : (($(".Fig_1").hasClass("Active")) && ($(".Fig_B").hasClass("Active"))) ? "Slide_1B"
              : (($(".Fig_1").hasClass("Active")) && ($(".Fig_3").hasClass("Active"))) ? "Slide_13"
              ...
```

I have this block (which is several lines longer) repeated a few times, for a different sect_# each time, and resultant set value (Slide_XY).

All the current suggestions are much appreciated. Keep it coming.

Comment: Use a map, and lower-casing. Don't know if the non-dummy code benefits, however--without knowing what you're *really* doing it's difficult to know how to help.

Comment: The code is readable, but not necessarily efficient. Without the `else` javascript will have no choice but to test for all the conditions.

Comment: @RosdiKasim, it's not `Java` instead 'javascript'.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, I corrected it. Since it is javascript, you could use `switch` instead of `if else`

Comment: @RosdiKasim, I'm not the `OP` and what about the `xdazz`'s answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var dic = {
  "a": "red",
  "b": "orange",
  "c": "yellow",
  "d": "green",
  "e": "blue",
  "f": "violet"
};

sOutput = $("#Input").text().toLowerCase();
lColor = dic[sOutput];
```

Comment: Although this is nice, I have no interest in converting to lowercase, that was just part of the example. If this formatting can support declaring multiple variables per 'if', then I'd like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object literal.

```
//extend the object as needed.
var obj = {
    'A': { sOutput:'a', lColor: 'red' },
    'B': { sOutput:'b', lColor: 'orange' },
}

var x = 'B';

console.log( obj[x] );
```

Edit:

You can even take this further and test to see if the 'x' variable's value even is defined:

```
var x = 'Z';

if( !(x in obj) ){
     //do stuff if Z isn't defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch` statement is readable. You could try any other fancy ways but for me, readable is priority number 1.

```
switch ($("#Input").text){
    case "A": 
        sOutput = "a"; 
        lColor = "red";
        break;
    case "B":
        sOutput = "b"; 
        lColor = "orange"; 
        break;
    case "C": 
       sOutput = "c"; 
       lColor = "yellow";
       break;
}
```

Comment: What if it were ($("#Input " + target + "_Container").text) and I want to flip through 'target' as well?

Comment: Sounds like you have similar sounding `css id`, in that case you should use proper jQuery 'ends with' or 'starts with' selector, refer here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to re-design my whole logic, and I developed something better.

Thanks for all the help though guys!